# Not getting auto-complete for JavaScript in new VsCode version

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, settings, javascript-intellisense

I used to get auto-complete and intellisence hints earlier but now I don't get auto-complete, nor do I get squiggly red line for errors. What do I do? Please help. I already spent 2 hours searching on google but can't find answer.

[image]

Others are getting proper suggestions like above. I ain't getting that. Below is my VsCode editor.

[image]

Comment: can you post your `settings.json` file?

Comment: You're gonna need to post a bit more about your configurations

Comment: I just now cleared my settings.json file because I wanted to reset to default. Therefore that settings file is empty now. { }

Comment: you should install JS helper `Extensions` in your VS Code. for example: "IntelliCode" and etc. also check your file extension be `.js`.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I had some problem in TypeScript settings where maybe by mistake I had unchecked autocomplete support i guess. I had fixed the issue now.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After surfing a lot in settings of VsCode, I finally figured out two things that might be causing this problem. Solved both of them and now the auto-complete is working fine for my nodeJs files in VsCode.

1. Install **ESLint** and **JavaScript (ES6) code snippets** extensions for providing intellisense for js code.

[image]

2. Enable auto-complete if you disabled it by mistake. This should fix the problem.
   settings > search javascript/typescript > search auto-complete in the extension settings and turn it on.

[image]

Comment: am using codeium and its not working in .ts but working in .tsx why!  although it shows the hints but when pressing tab it just do the tab without insertint the code